# Code to execute after return statement

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, return, execution

Just curious to improve the response time of my program with following idea, please help in executing it :

```
@Controller   
public class SendData{  
   @RequestMapping(value = "/getEmailId", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
   public String getUserMail(String userId) {  
      //getting Email Id From Database
      String emailId = getEmailIdFromDatabase(userId); 

      //send mail
      sendNotificationMail(emailId);

      // send data to requestor
      return emailId;  
     }  
}
```

Possible idea: To send Mail after returning `EmailId` to requestor

```
@Controller   
public class SendData{  
   @RequestMapping(value = "/getEmailId", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
   public String getUserMail(String userId) {  
      //getting Email Id From Database
      String emailId = getEmailIdFromDatabase(userId); 

      // send data to requestor
      return emailId;  

      //send mail
      sendNotificationMail(emailId);
     }  
}
```

As I am doing it in bit large scale (eg. I am getting list of `emailIds`) so I want requestor to first get the `emailIds` and remove the waiting time to send them notification mail.

- Please tell the solution if it is achievable by threading.
- If something like this is possible in any language other than Java?
- I have tried using finally block, but observed finally block executes before return statement.

Comment: You might want to look into java callbacks. They basically let you notify another piece of code that something happened (e.g. you got some emaiIiDs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible and naive solution is just to start a new thread for mail sending:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendNotificationMail(emailId);
    }
}.start();
```

A more robust version is to split between "I want send a mail" and "I send a mail". For example, instead of sending a mail just insert that mail in a table. With [@Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled) get inserted mail from the database, send it and delete it after that. So you can improve your response time. That it's. Sure, it's just an idea and you can use message bus or like, but you get the point.

Comment: Thanks threading works. Also the other provided solution is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the second block of code you proposed is not valid.
The code after the return statement is dead code, it won't be invoked at all, I guess java won't even let it compile.

I saw you are using Spring, so one solution to your problem would be to create a service to handle the email requests and use `JavaMailSender` class. This class can be configured using `properties.yml`, you can find a good example on following tutorial: [Sending HTML Mail with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf](http://dolszewski.com/spring/sending-html-mail-with-spring-boot-and-thymeleaf/)

To prevent it from blocking you just need to annotate the method responsible to send the email inside the Service class with `@Async`. This is most probably the best solution for your simple application.

PS: This solutions has some drawbacks. If your application needs to deal with lots of emails, it won't scale. To solve this you should look for a pattern where you will add requests to a queue and have another component of your architecture(a worker) just to be consuming the queue and sending the emails. Please bear in mind that this approach should be followed only if you really need it.

Comment: Are you sure about "This will handle threading out of the box and won't block your request till the email is sent."? I use JavaMailSender, but it blocks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. To have it work you have to add @Async on the method the sends the email inside your Service class. Let me edit my answer!

Comment: I know the second block will not work it is just an idea if we can achieve something like this. I will research more on your solution. Thank You

Comment: Yes, the link i sent will be perfect for you. Just pay attention to the class MailClient and to the method prepareAndSend, you should annotate this method with @Async so that your request does not block till the email is sent.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to the problem is to make your sendNotication service Asynchronous:

## 1. By using thread

```
new Thread() 
{
   @Override
   public void run() 
   {
      sendNotificationMail(emailId);
   }
}.start();
```

## 2. By using Java Messaging service

refer this URL : http://www.javatpoint.com/jms-tutorial